# Eclipse-based applications produce mouse and sound lags under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, audio, eclipse, lag

Strange problem. I have a huge Eclipse-based application that frequently spawns copy of its self. On each copy launch there is mouse and sound lags, overall responsiveness of a system is just terrible for 5-10 seconds. There is no such thing with other apps, no matter native, Java or .NET, but every Eclipse-based app I have tried gives that effect.

The machine is a little outdated (E8400, 4 GB, 9800 GTX+), but it handles everything I need pretty fast except Eclipse, even my laptop that is much slower in overall handles it well. There is no notable saturation in CPU, disk or memory usage.

What can I do with it, guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issues (AMD Athlon II X3, Intel x25M SSD, 8Gb RAM)
same lags with different jdks (from 1.6.09 to 1.7.21)
the only workaround I found is to reduce the priority of the eclipse process to "Below normal" from "Normal" before choosing worspace

Answer (score -1):

Close all unwated apps and free up some memory the, Reduce some Visual effects too. This might free up resources and could give a slight speed boost.