# Eclipse Mars slows down Windows 7 interface

Tags: windows-7, performance, gpu, eclipse

On a two pretty modern PCs I recently started to experience a strange problem. When I run Eclipse Mars, the Windows 7 GUI suddenly slows down, i.e. scrolling in Chrome, dragging the windows etc. I'd say everything related to hardware video-acceleration.

System Monitor tells that both CPU and GPU usage is 2-5%, no matter of eclipse window state. Memory, disk, etc. is fine too.

The problem disappears when I minimize the eclipse window or turn off Windows Aero. GPU and CPU usage remain the same, but the Windows GUI performance goes back to normal.

**Are there any switches in Eclipse to overcome this problem? Perhaps to disable GPU-acceleration in SWT?**

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/463874/eclipse-based-applications-produce-mouse-and-sound-lags-under-windows-7?rq=1 suggests to reduce the eclipse priority - seems has little effect

Comment: It seems eclipse uses 3D application settings (gaming-related) from ATI Catalyst. I've created a profile for eclipse.exe and turned everything to the lowest settings and seems it helped a bit.